# Correct set up for using ember-data.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What versions of various libraries do I actually need to get the Emberjs working with ember-data.js? This is quite frustrating.

I've got the latest ember.js from

http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js

and the latest ember-data.js from

http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/data/ember-data-latest.min.js

and the latest handlebars.js from

http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js

and jQuery 1.8.3 from

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js

and it gives me a load of errors.

Comment: Maybe use one of the ember starter kits instead, with the pre-reqs included: https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

1. jQuery 1.8.3 or later. The one you have now should work fine.
2. The Handlebars.js build from the [Handlebars.js website](http://handlebarsjs.com/), currently 1.0.0-RC.3.
3. The Ember.js build from [Ember.js website](http://www.emberjs.com/), currently 1.0.0-RC.1.
4. A current build of Ember Data. Presently you have to build it yourself using the instructions in the README on [the GitHub tracker](https://github.com/emberjs/data).